Getting Stream closed error with Mono.take
I am trying to use Mono.take to timeout the request if I don't get response in specific time. But issue is when I get timeout for one request, it's interuppting other requests also and getting Stream.closed error. SDK is of blocking nature and it's from third party can't do much in this.
Controller Code:
return util.callSdk(request)
                .map(ResponseUtil::prepareSuccessResponse)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(8,50000,"call-scheduler"))
                .doFinally(end -> {
                    clearMDC();
                    setMDCContext(callerMdc);
                    span.end();
                })
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    span.recordException(e);
                    return Mono.just(ResponseUtil.prepareErrorResponse(e));
                });

Util Code
public Mono<Response> callSdk(Request request) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> blockingSdk(request))
                .take(Duration.ofSeconds(requestTimeoutSeconds))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new TimeoutException("Request not completed in time")))
                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, ex -> handleExceptionMono(ex));
    }

Tried with Mono.take and Mono.timeout but same issue with both
I am trying to use Mono.take to timeout the request if I don't get response in specific time. But issue is when I get timeout for one request, it's interuppting other requests also and getting Stream.closed error.

One potential solution to handle timeouts without interrupting other requests is to use Mono.timeout(Duration, Mono) instead of Mono.take(Duration).

Tried using, but now request is not getting timeout after 10s
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10),Mono.error(new TimeoutException("timeout occurred")))
